# Using Repater to create new html page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, database

I am working in a website where each time I have to genrate a new page with data from the database . I tried to use Repeater for that but it doesn't work with me . Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate a Repeater control by using a `SQLDataSource` as shown in code below or by getting data from database in code-behind and then databinding the repeater control.

**Repeater Control Sample**

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
  <HeaderTemplate>
      <table>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
  </HeaderTemplate>

  <ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" 
            text='<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>' />
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" 
              text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
      </td>
  </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>

  <AlternatingItemTemplate>
  <tr>
      <td >
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label3" 
            text='<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>' />
      </td>
      <td >
         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label4" 
             text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
      </td>
  </tr>
  </AlternatingItemTemplate>

  <FooterTemplate>
      </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>



<asp:SqlDataSource 
      ConnectionString=
          "<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>"
      ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
      SelectCommand="SELECT [CategoryID], [CategoryName], 
          [Description] FROM [Categories]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

If you don't want to use SqlDataSource, then go for code-behind databinding as shown in snippet below.

**Repeater databinding in Page_Load event in code-behind**

```
      SqlDataReader dr = GetData();//some method to get data from database
      Repeater1.DataSource = dr);
      Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank You , but this will create a new row in a table each time . what I want is to create a new page each time .

Comment: What do you mean by a new page? You can always replace the row template html with your custom html template.

Comment: yes I know that I can replace the row templete to whatever I want . Lets assume a button will be in that row and when a user click that button a page appear to the user which has to be created automatically with some data from the database .

Comment: Yes you can do it. Just create your template. By page you mean populate some control like gridview or something else?

Comment: https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=Q1QBEK0N&id=4543D1C96B788E64FDFCA021D4FF828A754F67E5&thid=OIP.Q1QBEK0N1QPlT3QtuuhKngEsDf&q=scrum+board&simid=608048765480471316&selectedIndex=0&qpvt=scrum+board&ajaxhist=0                                                                                       the idea of the website is like that picture . The notes moves from one stage to other stage in my case the notes is buttons and when I click to that button a new html page should appear .

Comment: Create a template like in the above link and rebind the repeater in server-side onclick event of the button.

Comment: Also the buttons have to be created automatically each time the user finish the step 1 .

Comment: What is step 1?

Comment: I mean as what is in the link (the picture ) . the idea is each time the user finish step one and save it ; a button should appear in that list (for example 1 note is in the progress step) . If the user click that button a new page should appear with all data from previse step .

Comment: Then add all buttons of all steps to your html of page.   But set Visible property to false of all buttons to be shown in step 2 or step 3.  This will only show buttons for step1 initially,  then when user clicks on next button set the Visible property  to true for step 2 buttons,  but for all other buttons set it it to false.  Then for each step you apply a similar logic.

Comment: You could also use a repeater control for each step.  Then just databind each repeater according to current step but set Visible="false" for other repeaters.  But you can only use this approach if there is a repeating pattern on each step.